# Project boolean value in aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql

Is it possible to `project` the boolean value of an operation with MongoDB's aggregation framework?

For example, given an input document like so:

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "data": [
    {
      "val": 1
    },
    {
      "val": 2
    },
    {
      "val": 3
    },
    {
      "val": 4
    },
    {
      "val": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

And the operation being `$data.val > 3` I'd like to return:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "bool_val": 0
    },
    {
      "bool_val": 0
    },
    {
      "bool_val": 0
    },
    {
      "bool_val": 1
    },
    {
      "bool_val": 1
    }
  ],
  "ok": 1
}
```

This is what I came up with:

```
db.test.aggregate([{$match: {id: 123}}, 
                   {$unwind: "$data"}, 
                   {$project: {"bool_val": {"$data.val": {$gt: 3}}, _id: 0}} 
                  ])
```

Which produces the following error:

```
aggregate failed: {
  "errmsg": "exception: invalid operator '$data.val'", 
  "code": 15999,
  "ok": 0
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use [`$cond`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/):

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {id: 123}
    }, 
    {
        $unwind: "$data"
    }, 
    {
        $project: {
            "bool_val": { 
                $cond: [ {$gt: [ "$data.val", 3] }, 1, 0 ]
            }, 
            _id: 0
        }
    } 
])
```

Answer (score 1):

As a reference, the syntax for multiple conditions is:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {id: 123}
    }, 
    {
        $unwind: "$data"
    }, 
    {
        $project: {
            "bool_val": { $cond: [ {$and: [{$gt: ["$data.val", 3]}, 
                                            {$lte: ["$data.val", 5]} ]  
                        }, 1, 0]},
            _id: 0
        }
    } 
])
```